# Springboot @ConfigurationProperties nested yaml properties don't load

Tags: java, spring-boot

For some reason non-nested properties load but nested don't.

Configuration:

```
spring:
  profile: junit
  profiles:
    include: base
```

Config class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
public class MyFirstProperties {

    private String profile;
    private Profiles profiles;
    // getters and setters


    public class Profiles
    {
        private String include;
    // getters and setters
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyFirstProperties.class)
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String... args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        }
}
```

When I inject configuration class to my controller and call getter for a non-nested property it returns its value. But a getter for a nested property returns null.

Annotating inner class with ConfigurationProperties and its own prefix does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `profiles` property

```
private Profiles profiles = new Profiles();
```

That's it.

This happens because your inner `class` **isn't** `static`.
You cannot instantiate this type of `class` directly, but only inside the context of the enclosing one.

Make your `class` `static` and you'll be good to go

```
public static class Profiles { ... }
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Though it doesn't look right to me that all tutorials and docks say you don't have to call a property's constructor when adding a field.